# Does IGListkit provide the ability to implement an updating interface similar to Doppelganger/Doppelganger swift library?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, iglistkit

Anybody know if the animation style of [Doppelganger](https://github.com/wondermall/doppelganger)/Doppelganger-Swift is achievable using [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit)? If not, how could I go about it from scratch?

I was thinking to use views instead of cells and dynamically move each view and update their y position based on rank. Im trying to avoid this as the data I want to use is best represented as a table and I want to use components true to their design.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic CollectionViews (with cells that are updated and animated at runtime) are indeed achievable using [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit).

Most importantly, IGListKit goes the extra mile and provides you with out-of-the-box data model "diffing", so you don't have to worry about comparing existing data with incoming server data to figure out your UI view updates.